# Symfony route not working in production mode

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.8

A weird issue occurs when calling a action in a controller. 
In development-mode with the `app_dev.php`-prefix everything is working as expected. But in production mode the action returns with a `404`.

An `echo "test"; exit;` at the beginning of the action is still resulting in a 404, so the action is completely ignored.

But `app/console debug:router --env=prod` as well as `app/console debug:router --env=dev` is displaying the routes correctly.

In both environments:

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | blabla_trackfile_index                                  |
| Path         | /trackfile/{id}.{ext}                                   |
| Path Regex   | #^/trackfile/(?P<id>[^/\.]++)\.(?P<ext>[^/]++)$#s       |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | ANY                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: PumukitBasePlayerBundle:TrackFile:index    |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I already cleared the cache with console

`php app/console cache:clear
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

and manually (deleting the folder).

I already changed the `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`
 in src/app.php to `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);`, but the problem still persists in production mode.

**Update**

In `prod.log` are no entries.

Nginx log:

```
2017/07/06 10:19:29 [error] 1517#0: *159 open() "/var/www/test/web/trackfile/594b97d1e1db06824d8b4567.mp4" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: localhost, request: "GET /trackfile/594b97d1e1db06824d8$
```

So it looks like nginx is treating the requested route as a file or directory. Is this the problem? How can i fix this?

**Update 2**

```
/**
 * @Route("/trackfile/{id}.{ext}", name="blabla_trackfile_index" )
 */
public function indexAction($id, Request $request)
{
    echo "asdf"; exit;
}
```

Any other ideas or hints I can follow?

Comment: Have you checked the application logs ?

Comment: Can you show the the action's code? I suspect its because you have a typehint for $id and it fails to load an entity hence the 404.

Comment: You might want to append your nginx configuration aswell.

Comment: Maybe in your nginx config you have a statement to serve mp4 and other static content "as if" (without entering into rewriting url config).

Comment: @scandel yes thats the point.. now its working.

Comment: Have you tried to make the request with the app.php in the route. May be there is something wrong with the internal redirect.

Comment: @Carlos It's working with app.php :-|

Comment: In that case there should be something wrong in the web server configuration. The Apache conf dile or the .htaccess file https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html for more info